# I am getting the error Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

Here is my code that I have and I cannot figure out why the following code returns the error Operand should contain 1 column(s). I know that both queries work independantly of the query I have below. ANy help would be appreciated

```
SELECT * 
FROM 2014_summary, 2014_profiles 
WHERE 2014_summary.player_id = 2014_profiles.player_id AND tournament_id = 'bec904c4-b2a3-4eba-a2bc-335aca680a40' AND 2014_summary.player_id 
NOT IN
(SELECT 
    T1.*, 
    T2.player_id as primary_player_id 
FROM (SELECT id, lead_id, form_id, MAX(case when field_number = 1 then value end) display_name, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) email, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 6 then value end) tournament_name, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 3 then value end) primary_golfer, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 4 then value end) backup_golfer, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 5 then value end) date, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) tournament_id 
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` 
GROUP BY lead_id)T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as player_name, player_id FROM 2014_profiles)T2 ON T1.primary_golfer = T2.player_name
WHERE display_name = "Hosker" AND tournament_id != 'bec904c4-b2a3-4eba-a2bc-335aca680a40')
ORDER BY (last_name) ASC
```

Comment: And where do you get the error? Please add the complete error message.

Comment: it does not give me a specific line, the NOT IN is the new addition to the query to join them together

Comment: And what is the complete error message? It starts with *you have an error in your sql syntax ...*

Comment: that is it - #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `not in` is:

```
2014_summary.player_id NOT IN
    (SELECT  T1.*, T2.player_id as primary_player_id
```

MySQL doesn't know which column to use in the `select` for comparison to `player_id`.  So it returns an error.  Actually, this is ANSI standard SQL functionality, and all databases work this way.  The subquery in an `in` needs to return only one column.

I think you want:

```
2014_summary.player_id NOT IN
    (SELECT TT2.player_id
     . . .
```